# Export an HTML data to Excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I would like to export an html table to excel. This is the html code of the page I want to export, is this possible? The interface within excel doesn't recognize the table. What would a good starting point be?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png"
 href="https://ntl-slither.com/favicon.ico">
<title>NTL MOD - Team log</title>

<style>
.mysearch {
    background-color: white;
    width: 170px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: text;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.myPlayButton {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.myPlayButton:hover, .button:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    width: 170px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
.show {display: block;}

.table {
    display: table;
    width: 1412px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.tr { 
    display: table-row;
    width: 1212px;
    /*height: 16px;*/
}
/*.tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #ddd;}*/
.tr:hover {background-color: #00ffff;}
.td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.tnic { width:200px;}
.tsrv { width:180px;}
.tip { width:100px;}
.treg { width:100px;}
.tcou { width:100px;}
.tcit { width:120px;}
.tscr { width:50px;}
.tupd { width:120px;}
.taut { width:120px;}
.ttid { width:200px;}
.town { width:100px;}
.tver { width:50px;}
.tdet { width:250px;}

.vld {background-color: #ffaaaa;}

</style>
<script>


function myRefresh24(m) {
setParam("m",m, true);
}

function myinterval() {
var min= document.getElementById("myIntervalmin").value;
var max= document.getElementById("myIntervalmax").value;
if ((min.length == 10) && (max.length == 10)) {
  setParam("int", min + ':' + max, true);
  }
}
function myintervalrep() {
var x= document.getElementById("myIntervalmin");
var y= document.getElementById("myIntervalmax");
if (x.value > y.value) {y.value=x.value};
}
function myintervalchk() {
var x= document.getElementById("myIntervalmin");
var y= document.getElementById("myIntervalmax");
if (y.value <x.value) {y.value=x.value};
}

    function setParam(name, value, makenew) {

        var l = window.location;
        /* build params */
        var params = {};        
        var x = /(?:\??)([^=&?]+)=?([^&?]*)/g;   
     if ((typeof makenew !== 'undefined') && (makenew !== null )) {s="";}
        else var s = l.search;
        for(var r = x.exec(s); r; r = x.exec(s))
        {
            r[1] = decodeURIComponent(r[1]);
            if (!r[2]) r[2] = '%%';
            params[r[1]] = r[2];
        }

        /* set param */
        params[name] = encodeURIComponent(value);

        /* build search */
        var search = [];
        for(var i in params)
        {
            var p = encodeURIComponent(i);
            var v = params[i];
            if (v != '%%') p += '=' + v;
            search.push(p);
        }
        search = search.join('&');

        /* execute search */
        l.search = search;
    }

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it

window.onload = function() { 
  document.getElementById("mySearch").focus();
  mylocaltime();
}

function myRefresh() {
  window.location="/team/logout.php";
}

function myquicksearch() {
  var input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('mytarget');
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
table.style.display = "none";
  for (i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
      k=nodes[i].style.display;
      nodes[i].style.display = "table-row";
    } else {
      nodes[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
table.style.display = "block";
}

function mylocaltime() {
x = document.getElementById("myTable");
x.style.display = "none";
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("td tupd");
  for (i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    var today = new Date(nodes[i].innerText*1000);
     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
 var dd = today.getDate();
 var hh = today.getHours();
 var nn = today.getMinutes();
 var ss = today.getSeconds();
// var ms = today.getMilliseconds();
 if(dd<10) {dd = '0'+dd} ;
 if(mm<10) {mm = '0'+mm};
 if(hh<10) {hh = '0'+hh};
 if(nn<10) {nn = '0'+nn};
 if(ss<10) {ss = '0'+ss};
 var hrs = -(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
    nodes[i].innerText = yyyy +'-'+ mm +'-'+ dd + " " + hh +':'+ nn + ':' + ss + " (GMT" + ((hrs>0)? "+"+hrs:hrs)+")";

  }
x.style.display = "table";
}

function mysrt(e){
chkscr=document.getElementById("chkscr");
chkupd=document.getElementById("chkupd");
switch (e.id) {
case "chkscr": select=".tscr";
    chkscr.checked=true;chkscr.disabled=true;
    chkupd.checked=false;chkupd.disabled=false;
    break;
case "chkupd": select=".tupd";
    chkscr.checked=false;chkscr.disabled=false;
    chkupd.checked=true;chkupd.disabled=true;
    break;
}
tinysort(".mytarget",{selector:select,order:'desc'});
}

</script>
<script src="/js/tinysort.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style='background-color:grey;'>
<section style="display:block;width:1200px;">
<button id="message" class="button" onclick="myRefresh()">Logout</button>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="mysearch" id="mySearch" oninput="myquicksearch()" placeholder="Quick Search">
<button id="message" class="button" onclick="myRefresh24(1)">Past 1h</button>
<button id="message" class="button" onclick="myRefresh24(8)">Past 8h</button>
<button id="message" class="button" onclick="myRefresh24(24)">Past 24h</button>
<input type="date" class="mysearch" style="width:160px" id="myIntervalmin" onkeyup="myintervalrep()" onclick="myintervalrep()" onchange="myintervalrep()">
<input type="date" class="mysearch" style="width:160px" id="myIntervalmax" onkeyup="myintervalchk()" onclick="myintervalchk()" onchange="myintervalchk()">
<button class="button" onclick="myinterval()" style="width:50px;">Go</button>
</section>
<hr><span style="color:white;">TeamID: <b>knm-gK9muqTh97r0GApO</b> . Showing <b>2</b> rows from the last 1 hour(s)</span></span><a href="https://ntl-slither.com/team/teamkeys.php" style="float:right;color:cyan;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px">Team Keys</a><hr><span style="color:white;">Last login was on 2022-11-03 19:21:08 GMT+00:00 from ip 67.188.230.228</span><hr><div class="table" id="myTable"><div class="tr" style="background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;"><div class="td tnic">Nickname</div><div class="td tsrv">Server IP</div><div class="td tip">IP</div><div class="td treg">Region</div><div class="td tcou">Country</div><div class="td tcit">City</div><div class="td tscr">Score <input type="checkbox" onchange="mysrt(this)" id="chkscr"></div><div class="td tupd">Update Time <input type="checkbox" onchange="mysrt(this)" id="chkupd" checked="" disabled=""></div><div class="td taut">Auth Key</div><div class="td town">Key Owner</div><div class="td tver">Version</div><div class="td tdet">Details</div></div><div class="tr mytarget "><div class="td tnic">Player 1</div><div class="td tsrv">_GAME_MENU_</div><div class="td tip">x.x.49.11</div><div class="td treg">North America</div><div class="td tcou">United States</div><div class="td tcit"></div><div class="td tscr">10</div><div class="td tupd">1667503422</div><div class="td taut">4p014x16602j2804</div><div class="td town">Numerous</div><div class="td tver">7.9</div><div class="td tdet">FPS: 92 @ 71(90) ms @ 0 K/m</div></div><div class="tr mytarget "><div class="td tnic">Player 1</div><div class="td tsrv">147.135.37.157:444 US,NA</div><div class="td tip">x.x.49.11</div><div class="td treg">North America</div><div class="td tcou">United States</div><div class="td tcit"></div><div class="td tscr">13</div><div class="td tupd">1667503418</div><div class="td taut">4p014x16602j2804</div><div class="td town">Numerous</div><div class="td tver">7.9</div><div class="td tdet">FPS: 91 @ 65(90) ms @ 0 K/m</div></div></div>
<br>
<hr>
<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;color:white;display:block;line-height:12px;">
* GeoIP data might not be 100% accurate<br>
* Sometimes geoip details might be missing like no country or no city etc<br>
* Part of ip is hidden for privacy reasons<br>
* Rows in red mean invalid keys used (or disabled) at the time of play (available only since 2019-07-21)<br>
* Dates are converted to your local timezone<br>
* If you select a big interval to display your browser will work harder and longer to convert the dates<br>
* Due to different timezones, when selecting interval to display you might miss a few hours so go a day wider<br>
* For very many rows on screen you might better use browser's built-in search function (CTRL+F) to search for info. Quick search is meant for smaller content with high visibility results<br>
</span>
</body></html>
```

I have tried using the from web, from text, from xml and query functions within excel to import this data but for some reason excel does not recognize the table.

Comment: I don't see any table in the code you posted.  Can't you just copy and paste it into Excel?

Comment: If you execute the code in a browser you will see a table. However I was able to solve this. Copy and paste ruined the formatting because there are randomly blank cells which excel does not recognize and which make it hard to reformat. The solution was to use a data scraper. I found a chrome add-on that works well.

Comment: I was talking about an actual HTML <table>...</table> tag.  Not a <section> with a CSS rule to display it as a table.  I have copy and pasted many tables from web pages to Excel with no loss of formatting.  Since you found a solution that works for you then great.